# Wildcard module declaration - Typescript 3.5

Tags: typescript, svg

I can declare a module in TS:

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    const content: string
    export default content
}
```

then i can import it: `import svg from './src/file.svg`, no errors would be thrown.

But if i use `import svg from './src/file.svg?query`, then i would get an error: `Cannot find module ./src/file.svg?query`

Is there a possibility to treat `./src/file.svg?query` as `./src/file.svg`?

Comment: Have you tried `declare module "*.svg*"`?

Comment: Pattern '*.svg*' can have at most one '*' character.

Comment: hmm TypeScript docs would define that as declare module "*?query" { ... }, typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/… . Really not optimal, but there doesn't seem to be another solution.

Comment: @ford04 so i have to declare 2 modules: one without `?query` and another with `?query` ?

Comment: Yeah, seems so, I do not know another way. TypeScript docs do it like this - here the (now complete) link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations

Comment: Thanks, i've read this before. Also `?query` won't work, compiler still complains.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a custom TypeScript plugin, [here's an example](https://github.com/bluwy/vite-plugin-iso-import/blob/57e47618d296221b78a53b7ea166e0b8462ea168/src/index.js#L52-L76) of a plugin I built for a different purpose. It essentially strips `?client` and `?server` from the imports so that Typescript sees it without the queries. A similar change can be made for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper solution as far I can tell. The workaround that I'm using is to simply use:

`declare module '*'`

Of course this would treat everything as a valid module, which may be problematic with any type checking done by the IDE.